# Extract smaller table from pivot table pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, train-test-split

I want to split the following pivot table into training and testing sets (to evaluate recommendation system), and was thinking of extracting two tables with non-overlapping indices (userID) and column values (ISBN). How can I split it properly? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: If you have `scikit-learn` library, it has pretty good `test train split` function that can make splitting a dataframe very simple and easy.

Comment: Just FYI regarding your table, usually the format of recommendation data comes in the form of `user, product, rating`. The problem with your matrix is that there will be many values that have either null ratings or zero ratings (if zero represents a non-rating). This will result in a giant table with significant memory overhead and will grow exponentially when your user/product data grows.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @moys, can use `train_test_split` from `scikit-learn` after splitting your dataframe columns first for the non-overlapping column names.

Example:

`import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split`

Generate data:

`df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))`

Split df columns in some way, eg half:

`cols = int(len(df.columns)/2)
df_A = df.iloc[:, 0:cols]
df_B = df.iloc[:, cols:]`

Use train_test_split:

`train_A, test_A = train_test_split(df_A, test_size=0.33)
train_B, test_B = train_test_split(df_B, test_size=0.33)`